# displaying date in a period format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have the following table with values mentioned below.I have a label  which shows the date from the table.for the first date it should display as 07/06/2011 and from  the second date it should display as  below format,any one help me..

"Label:07/07/2011 to 07/13/2011 " ,

```
ID  Date                  
==  ==========
63  07/06/2011         
64  07/13/2011         
65  07/20/2011         
66  07/27/2011         
67  08/03/2011
```

Comment: Do you want a query that returns that string? If so, why those 2 dates in particular?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT a.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date) rn
      FROM MyTable a
)
SELECT a.Id,
       CASE 
        WHEN b.Id IS NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.Date, 101) 
        ELSE 'Label: ' + 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.Date + 1, 101) + 
              ' to ' + 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.Date , 101) 
       END AS Date
  FROM qry a LEFT JOIN qry b
    ON a.rn  = b.rn+1
```

Table Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (ID INT, DATE DATETIME)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(63,'07/06/2011');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(64,'07/13/2011');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(65,'07/20/2011');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(66,'07/27/2011');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(67,'08/03/2011');
```

Results:

```
Id  Date
63  07/06/2011
64  Label: 07/07/2011 to 07/13/2011
65  Label: 07/14/2011 to 07/20/2011
66  Label: 07/21/2011 to 07/27/2011
67  Label: 07/28/2011 to 08/03/2011
```

Comment: +1, at first I thought your query was wrong, the output looks strange.  however after reading the question a few more times, you seem to have what the Op wants.

Comment: Hi... the above code with row number  is working only in sql server 2005 and not in sql server 2000.can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on yout day/month format you could try:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, [date] , 4)
```